# How can I modify and forward a 'POST' request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, payment-gateway, payment

I've been dealing with `Payment using 3D Secure`. I have to POST the form data from the client side like following;

```
<form action="https://virtualpos.bank.com/servlet/3dgateway" method="post">
    Card Number: <input name="cardnumber" type="text" />
    Expiry Date (mm): <input name="expirydatemonth" type="text" />
    Expire Date (yy): <input name="expirydateyear" type="text" />
    CVV2: <input name="cardcvv2" type="text" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit the Payment" />
</form>
```

When submitting this form using POST method for 3dgateway address, the request is redirected to a 3D Secure Confirmation Page. Customers may enter the incoming SMS value in and confirm his credit card informations.

However, I have to add some other informations before send. Thus, I POST the form to my Node.js server using `/redirectingTo3DGateway` route. Then, I add other informations and POST the all values to `https://virtualpos.bank.com/servlet/3dgateway`.

After this point, I get the response as HTML (header as `Content-Type: text/html`). But I have to forward the content to the client side like a router. And the client must see `https://virtualpos.bank.com/servlet/3dgateway` in the address bar and must see 3D Gateway Page content. In the end, the page would work on `bank.com` server completely.

Would it be possible?

ps: Normally, this operations are performed on ASPX or JSP pages that are run on the server side. Therefore there is no problem.

Comment: Make sure that the terms of this service allows you to post this data to your server first... this could be seen as a security risk.

Comment: I couldn't find a valid way. My another chance, sending some descriptive (bank api account) informations to the client side in hidden inputs. Of course if a user press `F12` all data are in there.

Comment: The only way to get this information to the gateway as a post while having the client see the response as coming from the gateway is to have the client send the post variables.

Comment: So, no way. I guess I will take your advice. Thank you.